# Tmux causes Emacs glitch

Tags: emacs, terminal, tmux

Recently I started using Tmux, but I noticed that it causes a strange Emacs glitch. When I open source code for elisp or haskell, the comments aren't highlighted. Only the comment sign is (; in case of elisp, -- in case of haskell). The rest of the commented line is in normal colour. When I run Emacs outside of Tmux everything works as expected - the whole commented line is highlighted in a colour denoting a comment. Any ideas why this is happening?

SOLUTION:
Based on Stefan's comment I added this to my .emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 (custom-set-faces
  '(font-lock-comment-face ((((class color)
                              (min-colors 8)
                              (background dark))
                              (:foreground "red"))))))
```

Now the comments are displayed in red, just like comment delimiters.

Comment: This is a software behavior question, not a programming question and is thus better suited for superuser, no wait, serverfault. no wait, i dont know, but somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is due to Emacs using a different coloring scheme when the number of colors is too limited.  So the underlying cause of the difference is that in Tmux, the number of colors available is restricted (I don't know why).  You can also change (with `M-x customize-face RET`) the faces `font-lock-comment-face` and `font-lock-command-delimiter-face` to simply work around the problem.

Comment: One possibility is to start `tmux` with the `-2` option (256-color support) and to make sure you set `TERM` to `screen-256color` inside `tmux`.

Comment: Thanks chepner. Your solution works, but it also causes other colours to change.